# The space shuttle returned to the earth

Tags: articles, definite-articles

```
1.The earth moves round the sun.
```

```
2.We live on earth.
```

```
3. The space shuttle returned to earth.
```

I know that the definite article  *the* is  used  before the word earth when it is considered a planet.

2. When we think of earth as human habitation, we do not use the definite article *the*.

3.I know that the definite article is not used in idioms such as *come down to earth.*

But in sentence 3 *the space shuttle returned to earth* , is earth considered a planet or human habitation? It seems that it is considered human habitation.

I have taken all the sentences from Longman's Active study dictionary. Page number 276.

Is it wrong to say **The space shuttle  returned to the earth?**

Comment: Note that Longman capitalises *earth* in its definition of *space shuttle*: ["*a vehicle that is designed to go into space and **return to Earth** several times*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/space-shuttle)

Comment: @Mari-LouA.The sentences are from Longman''s dictionary. It says the space shuttle returned to earth but not the earth.

Comment: @Mari-LouA.I know it is a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) actually addresses this issue:

> Originally, earth was written in lowercase, and from early Middle
>   English, its definite sense as "the globe" was expressed as *the earth*.
>   By Early Modern English, many nouns were capitalized, and *the earth*
>   became (and often remained) *the Earth*, particularly when referenced
>   along with other heavenly bodies. More recently, the name is sometimes
>   simply given as *Earth*, by analogy with the names of the other planets.

I'd say 'sometimes' should be replaced by 'often'. But the use of the article is optional, and almost certainly style-driven (anarthrous *Earth* being less familiar, homely ... more clinical).

Comment: Had to look up [anarthrous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anarthrous). This, I guarantee, I will never remember.

Comment: Surely the anarthrous is here to stay?

Comment: Ah; cut-and-paste doesn't work accurately. Thanks; will do.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth.An excellent answer. Earth neither be capitalized nor be used with the article* the*.I have upvoted and accepted your answer

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm surprised that *you* used Wikipedia!  It seems so "mere mortal" of a source!!! ;)

Comment: @David M Dodging the Earthling pun (and the improper canonisation): I was persuaded quite a while ago that _Wikipedia_ nowadays is often well worth considering. It has lost a lot of the (probably merited) criticism of its earlier incarnations, and accuracy of content has been vastly improved. In fact, it performed as well as _Britannica_ in a well designed test for accuracy a few years ago. But like all 'authorities' (even CGEL), it should be used judiciously and critically. Of course we then have the problem "Who decides on when to go with authority X? Are we fit judges?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I use it all the time.  And, like you said, all must be read with a critical eye.

Answer (score 1):

It's [unidiomatic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unidiomatic) to say *The shuttle returned to **the** earth*. Earth is used as a proper noun here, it is the name of a place, it's like saying "The train arrived at Genova" or "We returned to Brussels". No article is needed.

Note that *Longman* Dictionary capitalises *earth* in its definition of *space shuttle*:

> ["*a vehicle that is designed to go into space and **return to Earth** several times*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/space-shuttle)

Comment: No.In the example earth was not capitalized

Comment: @JVL I have included the Longman dictionary link in my answer, and  the word *earth* is capitalised there. I suggest you also include the link in your question.

Comment: @Marie-Lou A. I am unable to provide the link.I can give the page number.page number 276.